# How to Read Specific DIV contents using C# in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, email, c#-4.0, stringbuilder

I have a requirement for sending the mail to Client with specific section say div of an `aspx` page. I have created a sample method which executes the page on `server` and returns the HTML markup in a `StringBuilder` object.
  This works fine. Now, Just i want to get the `HTML` of Specific Div Content and not the Whole returned page content.

Code:

```
    protected void ReadPage()
        {
            //StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("CompleteOrder.aspx"));
            //string readFile = reader.ReadToEnd();

            ////*** somewhere in an aspx page - preferably a different one to the one you are emailing but doesnt have to be******
            StringWriter pageContents = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(pageContents);
            Server.Execute("CompleteOrder.aspx", htw);
            MailBiz ObjMailBiz = new MailBiz();
            string Username = Session["UserName"].ToString();
            string email = Session["EmailID"].ToString();
            string strSubject = "Test Mail";
            bool issent = ObjMailBiz.SendEmail(Username, email, strSubject, pageContents.ToString());
            if (issent)
            {
                //mail sent successfully
            }
            else
            {
                //failed to sent the mail


      }
}
```

**Just i want to know how to read specific Div content from this returned string ?** 
Eg: Read the div with id="content" `(<div id='content'>some other innerdivs tables etc</div>)`

Help Appreciated!

Comment: Have a look into the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Sorry!Dont want to use any external APIs...! :(

Comment: Why not - why spend lots of time doing it roughly when someone has done it properly for you for free! (Note this is a widely used library - has over .5 million downloads on NuGet). If not then probably just string parsing of the stringwriter will have to do (eg you know what your div start tag looks like)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to load the HTML and search for the relevant `div` like this:

```
StringWriter pageContents = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(pageContents);
Server.Execute("CompleteOrder.aspx", htw);

HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(pageContents.ToString());

HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='content']");

...Here you can access node.InnerText for your message
```

Comment: You might want the `InnerHtml` property, to preserve markup ("inner divs, tables etc")

Answer (score 0):

Put runat server attribute in Div. 
so it will be available in c# code.

For your example 
use

> content.innerHTML

or

> content.InnerText

to get div contents

Thanks

Comment: No! your are not getting it! what i mean is I am executing the page on server and returning the HTML Markup and from that markup read specific div contents. NOT THE DIV content from Code Behind..!

Comment: sorry for not getting your point. but now i think in that case you should use xml parser assuming HTML string as xml. i guess it will give well formed value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use user control instead of page and then load control in page element then findcontrol like this

```
Page pa = new Page();
pa.LoadControl("CompleteOrder.ascx");
pa.FindControl("content");
```

Comment: The OP is after the rendered output, not the server side controls.